# .NET Standard cross runtime binary serialisation, what is supported on ALL runtimes?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-core, .net-standard

The only thing I could find is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization

Which shows that .net core 2.0.4 + and .net framework 4.5.1 + have a subset (which is largely sufficient for me), that is safe to serialize and deserialize on either end.

It says mono "should" work unofficially, however, I see nothing about Xamarin and wonder if I can use this in a project with a .net core server where consumers will be IOS Android windows with .net and UWP. Does anyone have a definitive answer on what is safe (or if it's safe at all) to count on binary serialization for a .NET standard DLL that will be shared across pretty much every supported platform?

I only need to serialize POCO that uses very simple types, even something much more restrictive would do, what I need boils down to :

1. Char
2. Strings
3. Guid's
4. All sizes and types of the built-in numeric type
5. `List<T>` where T is one of the types listed here or a POCO type containing only the types listed here
6. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` where Tkey and TValue have the same constraint as T for the previously mentioned list type

Can I just go with `BinaryFormatter` or won't it be binary compatible for IOS/Android on Xamarin?

Comment: Why use binary?  It's not meant to be interoperable across various systems. If interoperability is important, then use something that is meant to be interoperable.

Comment: Umm, I do not see any reasons for using binary...

Comment: @Amy But the very link i posted shows microsoft is making it interoperable. And using it would simplify things if that interoperability is guaranteed on all platforms

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Where in your link does it show that?  Binary is not meant to be interoperable, at all.

Comment: @G.hakim For simplicity and performance (on the client, server, and on the wire) without adding third party components, but only if it's also guaranteed to work on xamarin

Comment: @Amy in the .net core section "The defined set of types are guaranteed to be serializable between .NET Framework 4.5.1 and later versions and .NET Core 2.0 and later versions. Other .NET implementations, such as Mono, aren't officially supported but should also be working."

Comment: BinaryFormatter enforces little-endian convention everywhere so it ought to work, as long as you go from .NET to .NET. Interoperating with other platforms is a wholly different matter.

Comment: @HenkHolterman aye i know that, my question is strictly about other runtimes not other processor architectures

Comment: So, then the answer simply is "yes" ??

Comment: @HenkHolterman Do you have a source? If you read my question i couldn't find a confirmation for xamarin, only for .net core and .net framework?

Comment: Well, I couldn't find a source to the contrary either. I don't know Mono that well but it seems unlikely they would break a spec like this.